# How to resolve Internal Server Error while calling Webservice request through PLSQL

Tags: xml, oracle, soap, plsql

--PLSQL Stub to call webservice request

```
  declare
       http_version     VARCHAR2(30) := '1.1';
       g_const_post CONSTANT VARCHAR2(5) := 'POST';
       http_method      VARCHAR2(10) := g_const_post;
       l_request        utl_http.req;
       l_response       utl_http.resp;
       l_req_ref        gwtbs_msg_in_log.msg_ref_no%TYPE;
       l_process_status gwtbs_msg_in_log.process_status%TYPE;
       buffer           VARCHAR2(2000);
       offset           PLS_INTEGER := 1;
       eob              BOOLEAN;
       p_error_code     ertb_msgs.err_code%type;
       p_error_prms     ertb_msgs.message%type;
       p_request_msg    clob := null;
       g_timeout       cstbs_param.param_val%TYPE:=3600;
       g_ws_method     cstbs_param.param_val%TYPE;
       g_url_key_store cstbs_param.param_val%TYPE;
       g_url_key_pass  cstbs_param.param_val%TYPE;
       g_http_type     cstbs_param.param_val%TYPE;
       g_http_url      cstbs_param.param_val%TYPE;
       g_https_url     cstbs_param.param_val%TYPE;
       g_http_response utl_http.resp;
       g_const_200              CONSTANT VARCHAR2(3) := '200';
       g_const_s                CONSTANT VARCHAR2(1) := 'S';
       g_const_f                CONSTANT VARCHAR2(1) := 'F';
       g_const_msg_gen_failed   CONSTANT VARCHAR2(20) := 'GW-ROUT0014';
       g_const_em_http055       CONSTANT VARCHAR2(20) := 'EM-HTTP055';
       g_const_web_service_fail CONSTANT VARCHAR2(20) := 'ST-FCWS-ERR';
       pkg_ws_data cstm_extws_master%ROWTYPE;
       p_response_msg CLOB;
       
     
       PROCEDURE dbg(MSG VARCHAR2) IS
       BEGIN
         -- DEBUG.PR_DEBUG('ST', 'stpks_invoke_reisws_custom --> ' || MSG);
         dbms_output.put_line('PM_Template --> ' || MSG);
       END DBG;
     
     BEGIN
       dbg('Started fn_process_util_http_request.........');
       select msg into p_request_msg from migt_pm_messages_SICB;
     
     -- g_http_url := 'http://10.11.4.243:8201/PMWeb/PMBookTransferSIService?WSDL';
       g_http_url := 'http://10.11.4.243:8201/PMWeb/PMBookTransferSIService';
       --g_http_url := 'http://localhost:8001/PMWeb/PMSIMaintenanceService?WSDL';
       --g_http_url := 'http://localhost:8001/PMWeb/PMBookTransferSIService';
       IF http_version = '1.0' THEN
         http_version := utl_http.http_version_1_0;
       END IF;
     
       IF http_version = '1.1' THEN
         http_version := utl_http.http_version_1_1;
       END IF;
     
       --Log Request Msg      
       utl_http.set_cookie_support(TRUE);
       utl_http.set_follow_redirect(3);
       utl_http.set_persistent_conn_support(TRUE);
     
       dbg('Connecting to URL..................' || g_http_url);
       BEGIN
         dbg('Connecting to URL..................' || g_http_url);
         dbg('HTTP_METHOD..................' || http_method);
         dbg('HTTP_VERSION..................' || http_version);
         l_request := utl_http.begin_request(g_http_url,
                                             http_method,
                                             http_version);
       EXCEPTION
         WHEN utl_http.request_failed THEN
           dbg('Failed in connecting to url : ' ||
               utl_http.get_detailed_sqlerrm);
           dbg(dbms_utility.format_error_backtrace);
           p_error_code := g_const_web_service_fail;
           p_error_prms := 'Currently Web Service Is Not Reachable';
           --RETURN FALSE;
         WHEN OTHERS THEN
           dbg('Failed Others in connecting to url : ' ||
               utl_http.get_detailed_sqlerrm);
           dbg(dbms_utility.format_error_backtrace);
           p_error_code := g_const_web_service_fail;
           p_error_prms := 'Currently Web Service Is Not Reachable1';
           --RETURN FALSE;
       END;
     
       dbg('Connected Successfully to .........');
       dbg('URL          =  ' || l_request.url);
       dbg('METHOD       =  ' || l_request.method);
       dbg('HTTP_VERSION =  ' || l_request.http_version);
       
     
       dbg('Setting Request message into the HTTP request......');
    
     
        
       utl_http.set_header(l_request,
                           'Content-Type',
                           'text/xml; charset=utf-8');
                           
        UTL_HTTP.SET_HEADER(l_request, 'Content-Type', 'text/xml');
        UTL_HTTP.SET_HEADER(l_request, 'Content-Length', LENGTH(p_request_msg));
        UTL_HTTP.SET_HEADER(l_request, 'SOAPAction', 'HTTP');
     
      /* utl_http.set_header(l_request,
                           'Authorization',
                           'Basic ' ||
                           utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(utl_encode.base64_encode(utl_i18n.string_to_raw(pkg_ws_data.ws_user || ':' ||
                                                                                                    pkg_ws_data.ws_pwd,
                                                                                                    'AL32UTF8'))));*/
      -- utl_http.set_header(l_request, 'Content-Length', length(p_request_msg));
       --utl_http.set_header(l_request, 'CountryCode', 'CMR'); -- to be changed
      -- utl_http.set_header(l_request, 'ApplicationCode', 'FCUB');
       utl_http.set_transfer_timeout(g_timeout);
       
       utl_http.write_text(l_request, p_request_msg);
       
       dbg('Completed setting Request message into the HTTP request');
     
       dbg('Posting Request message to web service........');
       dbg('p_request_msg:');
       dbg(p_request_msg);
       dbg('l_request:');
      --dbg(l_request.req);
       
       l_response := utl_http.get_response(l_request);
     
       dbg('Response from web service........');
       dbg('STATUS CODE    =  ' || l_response.status_code);
       dbg('REASON PHRASE  =  ' || l_response.reason_phrase);
       dbg('HTTP VERSION   =  ' || l_response.http_version);
       dbg('Got Response');
     
       -- END-OF-BODY flag (Boolean)
      eob := FALSE;
     
       WHILE NOT (eob) LOOP
         BEGIN
           dbg('looping->' || offset);
           utl_http.read_text(l_response, buffer, 15000);
           dbg('Extracted value' || buffer);
           IF buffer IS NOT NULL AND length(buffer) > 0 THEN
             p_response_msg := p_response_msg || buffer;
           END IF;
         EXCEPTION
           WHEN utl_http.end_of_body THEN
             eob := TRUE;
           WHEN OTHERS THEN
             eob := TRUE;
         END;
         offset := offset + 1;
       END LOOP;
       
       UTL_HTTP.read_raw(l_response, buffer, 32767);
      
     
       --set_http_response(l_response);
       g_http_response := l_response;
       utl_http.end_response(l_response);
    --   dbg('p_response_msg in ext comm custom....:' || p_response_msg);
     
       IF l_response.status_code = g_const_200 THEN
         l_process_status := g_const_s;
       ELSE
         l_process_status := g_const_f;
       END IF;
     
       dbg(' Error Code: ' || p_error_code);
       dbg(' Error Params: ' || p_error_prms);
       dbg(' Status Code: ' || l_response.status_code);
     
       IF l_response.status_code = g_const_200 THEN
         dbg('Processed in webservice ....');
         --RETURN TRUE;
       ELSE
         dbg('Error in process in communication channel HTTP code' ||
             l_response.status_code || '~' || l_response.reason_phrase);
         dbg(dbms_utility.format_error_backtrace);
        -- RETURN TRUE;
       END IF;
     
     EXCEPTION
       WHEN no_data_found THEN
         dbg('No data found in fn_process_util_http_request due to' || SQLERRM);
         dbg(dbms_utility.format_error_backtrace);
         p_error_code := g_const_em_http055;
         p_error_prms := SQLERRM || '';
        -- RETURN FALSE;
       WHEN OTHERS THEN
         dbg('Failed in others of fn_process_util_http_request due to' ||
             SQLERRM);
         dbg(dbms_utility.format_error_backtrace);
         p_error_code := g_const_em_http055;
         p_error_prms := SQLERRM || '';
        -- RETURN FALSE;
     END
```

SOAP XML request for webservice call

```
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:pmx="http://pmts.ofss.com/ws/PMXborderOutSIService">
       <soapenv:Header/>
       <soapenv:Body>
          <pmx:CREATEXBORDEROUTSI_FSFS_REQ>
             <pmx:FCUBS_HEADER>
                <pmx:SOURCE>FCAT</pmx:SOURCE>
                <pmx:UBSCOMP>FCUBS</pmx:UBSCOMP>
                
                <pmx:MSGID></pmx:MSGID>
                
                <pmx:CORRELID></pmx:CORRELID>
                <pmx:USERID>FCATOP</pmx:USERID>
                
                <pmx:ENTITY></pmx:ENTITY>
                <pmx:BRANCH>000</pmx:BRANCH>
                
                <pmx:MODULEID></pmx:MODULEID>
                <pmx:SERVICE>PMXborderOutSIService</pmx:SERVICE>
                <pmx:OPERATION>CreateXborderOutSI</pmx:OPERATION>
                
                <pmx:SOURCE_OPERATION></pmx:SOURCE_OPERATION>
                
                <pmx:SOURCE_USERID></pmx:SOURCE_USERID>
                
                <pmx:DESTINATION></pmx:DESTINATION>
                
                <pmx:MULTITRIPID></pmx:MULTITRIPID>
                
                <pmx:FUNCTIONID></pmx:FUNCTIONID>
                
                <pmx:ACTION></pmx:ACTION>
                
                <pmx:MSGSTAT></pmx:MSGSTAT>
                
                <pmx:SNAPSHOTID></pmx:SNAPSHOTID>
                
                <pmx:PASSWORD></pmx:PASSWORD>
                
                <pmx:ADDL>
                   
                   <pmx:PARAM>
                      <pmx:NAME></pmx:NAME>
                      <pmx:VALUE></pmx:VALUE>
                   </pmx:PARAM>
                </pmx:ADDL>
             </pmx:FCUBS_HEADER>
             <pmx:FCUBS_BODY>
                <pmx:Contract-Master-Full>
                   <pmx:SOURCE_CODE>SI</pmx:SOURCE_CODE>
                   <pmx:TRANSFER_TYPE>C</pmx:TRANSFER_TYPE>
                   
                   <pmx:MULTIPLE_TXN></pmx:MULTIPLE_TXN>
                   
                   <pmx:RELATED_REF_NO>12345</pmx:RELATED_REF_NO>
                   
                   <pmx:IMAGE_REF_NO></pmx:IMAGE_REF_NO>
                   
                   <pmx:EXTERNAL_REF_NO></pmx:EXTERNAL_REF_NO>
                   
                   <pmx:BOOK_DATE>2021-03-31</pmx:BOOK_DATE>
                   
                   <pmx:ORDERING_CUSTOMER_ID_CODE></pmx:ORDERING_CUSTOMER_ID_CODE>
                   
                   <pmx:ORDERING_CUSTOMER1></pmx:ORDERING_CUSTOMER1>
                   
                   <pmx:ORDERING_CUSTOMER2>BICIMLBAXXX</pmx:ORDERING_CUSTOMER2>
                   
                   <pmx:ORDERING_CUSTOMER3></pmx:ORDERING_CUSTOMER3>
                   
                   <pmx:ORDERING_CUSTOMER4></pmx:ORDERING_CUSTOMER4>
                   
                   <pmx:ORDERING_CUSTOMER5></pmx:ORDERING_CUSTOMER5>
                   
                   <pmx:ORD_CUST_COUNTRY></pmx:ORD_CUST_COUNTRY>
                   
                   <pmx:ORDERING_INSTITUTION1></pmx:ORDERING_INSTITUTION1>
                   
                   <pmx:ORDERING_INSTITUTION2></pmx:ORDERING_INSTITUTION2>
                   
                   <pmx:ORDERING_INSTITUTION3></pmx:ORDERING_INSTITUTION3>
                   
                   <pmx:ORDERING_INSTITUTION4></pmx:ORDERING_INSTITUTION4>
                   
                   <pmx:ORDERING_INSTITUTION5></pmx:ORDERING_INSTITUTION5>
                   
                   <pmx:INTERMEDIARY1>BIC</pmx:INTERMEDIARY1>
                   
                   <pmx:INTERMEDIARY2_CODE></pmx:INTERMEDIARY2_CODE>
                   
                   <pmx:INTERMEDIARY3></pmx:INTERMEDIARY3>
                   
                   <pmx:INTERMEDIARY4></pmx:INTERMEDIARY4>
                   
                   <pmx:INTERMEDIARY5></pmx:INTERMEDIARY5>
                   
                   <pmx:INTERMEDIARY6></pmx:INTERMEDIARY6>
                   
                   <pmx:INSTRUCTION_DATE>2021-03-31</pmx:INSTRUCTION_DATE>
                   
                   <pmx:TXN_CCY>USD</pmx:TXN_CCY>
                   
                   <pmx:TXN_AMOUNT>40</pmx:TXN_AMOUNT>
                   
                   <pmx:DR_AC_CCY>USD</pmx:DR_AC_CCY>
                   
                   <pmx:SENDER_BANK></pmx:SENDER_BANK>
                   
                   <pmx:ACC_WITH_INST1>BIC</pmx:ACC_WITH_INST1>
                   
                   <pmx:ACC_WITH_INST2_CODE></pmx:ACC_WITH_INST2_CODE>
                   
                   <pmx:ACC_WITH_INST3></pmx:ACC_WITH_INST3>
                   
                   <pmx:ACC_WITH_INST4></pmx:ACC_WITH_INST4>
                   
                   <pmx:ACC_WITH_INST5></pmx:ACC_WITH_INST5>
                   
                   <pmx:ACC_WITH_INST6></pmx:ACC_WITH_INST6>
                   
                   <pmx:BENEFICIARY1>/2345671234</pmx:BENEFICIARY1>
                   
                   <pmx:BENEFICIARY2>BICIMLBAXXX</pmx:BENEFICIARY2>
                   
                   <pmx:BENEFICIARY3></pmx:BENEFICIARY3>
                   
                   <pmx:BENEFICIARY4></pmx:BENEFICIARY4>
                   
                   <pmx:BENEFICIARY5></pmx:BENEFICIARY5>
                   
                   <pmx:BENEFICIARY_COUNTRY>ML</pmx:BENEFICIARY_COUNTRY>
                   
                   <pmx:MFA_CHECKER_ID></pmx:MFA_CHECKER_ID>
                   
                   <pmx:MAKERID2></pmx:MAKERID2>
                   
                   <pmx:DE_MAKER_DT></pmx:DE_MAKER_DT>
                   
                   <pmx:CHECKER_ID></pmx:CHECKER_ID>
                   
                   <pmx:DE_CHECKER_DT></pmx:DE_CHECKER_DT>
                   
                   <pmx:AUTH_STATUS></pmx:AUTH_STATUS>
                   
                   <pmx:IGNORE_CUTOFF></pmx:IGNORE_CUTOFF>
                   
                   <pmx:WAIVE_CHARGES></pmx:WAIVE_CHARGES>
                   
                   <pmx:SPREAD_CODE></pmx:SPREAD_CODE>
                   
                   <pmx:CONSOL_REF_NO></pmx:CONSOL_REF_NO>
                   
                   <pmx:EXCH_RATE></pmx:EXCH_RATE>
                   
                   <pmx:CHARGE_WHOM></pmx:CHARGE_WHOM>
                   
                   <pmx:PRIORITY></pmx:PRIORITY>
                   
                   <pmx:BENEFICIARY_INST1></pmx:BENEFICIARY_INST1>
                   
                   <pmx:BIC_NAME_ADDR></pmx:BIC_NAME_ADDR>
                   
                   <pmx:BENEFICIARY_INST3></pmx:BENEFICIARY_INST3>
                   
                   <pmx:BENEFICIARY_INST4></pmx:BENEFICIARY_INST4>
                   
                   <pmx:BENEFICIARY_INST5></pmx:BENEFICIARY_INST5>
                   
                   <pmx:BENEF_BANK_COUNTRY></pmx:BENEF_BANK_COUNTRY>
                   
                   <pmx:PAYMENT_DETAILS1></pmx:PAYMENT_DETAILS1>
                   
                   <pmx:PAYMENT_DETAILS2></pmx:PAYMENT_DETAILS2>
                   
                   <pmx:PAYMENT_DETAILS3></pmx:PAYMENT_DETAILS3>
                   
                   <pmx:PAYMENT_DETAILS4></pmx:PAYMENT_DETAILS4>
                   
                   <pmx:SNDR_TO_RCVR_INFO1></pmx:SNDR_TO_RCVR_INFO1>
                   
                   <pmx:SNDR_TO_RCVR_INFO2></pmx:SNDR_TO_RCVR_INFO2>
                   
                   <pmx:SNDR_TO_RCVR_INFO3></pmx:SNDR_TO_RCVR_INFO3>
                   
                   <pmx:SNDR_TO_RCVR_INFO4></pmx:SNDR_TO_RCVR_INFO4>
                   
                   <pmx:SNDR_TO_RCVR_INFO5></pmx:SNDR_TO_RCVR_INFO5>
                   
                   <pmx:SNDR_TO_RCVR_INFO6></pmx:SNDR_TO_RCVR_INFO6>
                   
                   <pmx:INTERNAL_REMARKS></pmx:INTERNAL_REMARKS>
                   
                   <pmx:ORDERED_CCY></pmx:ORDERED_CCY>
                   
                   <pmx:ORDERED_AMT></pmx:ORDERED_AMT>
                   
                   <pmx:MULTI_CR_REF_NO></pmx:MULTI_CR_REF_NO>
                   
                   <pmx:MULTI_CUSTOMER_TRANSFER></pmx:MULTI_CUSTOMER_TRANSFER>
                   
                   <pmx:RECEIVER></pmx:RECEIVER>
                   
                   <pmx:RECEIVER_OF_COVER></pmx:RECEIVER_OF_COVER>
                   
                   <pmx:BANKING_PRIORITY></pmx:BANKING_PRIORITY>
                   
                   <pmx:MFA_MAKER_ID></pmx:MFA_MAKER_ID>
                   
                   <pmx:BRANCH_CODE>000</pmx:BRANCH_CODE>
                   
                   <pmx:PAYMENT_TYPE>X</pmx:PAYMENT_TYPE>
                   
                   <pmx:NETWORK>SWIFT1</pmx:NETWORK>
                   
                   <pmx:CUTOFF_STATUS></pmx:CUTOFF_STATUS>
                   
                   <pmx:MESSAGE_DATE>2021-03-31</pmx:MESSAGE_DATE>
                   
                   <pmx:RECEIVED_DATE_TIME></pmx:RECEIVED_DATE_TIME>
                   
                   <pmx:DR_AMOUNT>40</pmx:DR_AMOUNT>
                   
                   <pmx:DR_VALUE_DATE>2021-03-31</pmx:DR_VALUE_DATE>
                   
                   <pmx:CR_VALUE_DATE>2021-03-31</pmx:CR_VALUE_DATE>
                   
                   <pmx:CR_AC_NO>000000100402003USD</pmx:CR_AC_NO>
                   
                   <pmx:CR_AC_CCY>USD</pmx:CR_AC_CCY>
                   
                   <pmx:CR_AMOUNT></pmx:CR_AMOUNT>
                   
                   <pmx:PAYMENT_BY></pmx:PAYMENT_BY>
                   
                   <pmx:BANK_OPER_CODE>CRED</pmx:BANK_OPER_CODE>
                   
                   <pmx:TXN_TYPE>O</pmx:TXN_TYPE>
                   
                   <pmx:INSTR_CODE1></pmx:INSTR_CODE1>
                   
                   <pmx:INSTR_CODE2></pmx:INSTR_CODE2>
                   
                   <pmx:INSTR_CODE3></pmx:INSTR_CODE3>
                   
                   <pmx:INSTR_CODE4></pmx:INSTR_CODE4>
                   
                   <pmx:INSTR_CODE5></pmx:INSTR_CODE5>
                   
                   <pmx:INSTR_CODE6></pmx:INSTR_CODE6>
                   
                   <pmx:OUR_CORRESPONDENT></pmx:OUR_CORRESPONDENT>
                   
                   <pmx:OUR_CORRESPONDENT2></pmx:OUR_CORRESPONDENT2>
                   
                   <pmx:OUR_CORRESPONDENT3></pmx:OUR_CORRESPONDENT3>
                   
                   <pmx:OUR_CORRESPONDENT4></pmx:OUR_CORRESPONDENT4>
                   
                   <pmx:OUR_CORRESPONDENT5></pmx:OUR_CORRESPONDENT5>
                   
                   <pmx:RCVR_CORRESP1></pmx:RCVR_CORRESP1>
                   
                   <pmx:RCVR_CORRESP2></pmx:RCVR_CORRESP2>
                   
                   <pmx:RCVR_CORRESP3></pmx:RCVR_CORRESP3>
                   
                   <pmx:RCVR_CORRESP4></pmx:RCVR_CORRESP4>
                   
                   <pmx:RCVR_CORRESP5></pmx:RCVR_CORRESP5>
                   
                   <pmx:THIRD_REIMB_INST1></pmx:THIRD_REIMB_INST1>
                   
                   <pmx:THIRD_REIMB_INST2></pmx:THIRD_REIMB_INST2>
                   
                   <pmx:THIRD_REIMB_INST3></pmx:THIRD_REIMB_INST3>
                   
                   <pmx:THIRD_REIMB_INST4></pmx:THIRD_REIMB_INST4>
                   
                   <pmx:THIRD_REIMB_INST5></pmx:THIRD_REIMB_INST5>
                   
                   <pmx:SNDR_CHG_CCY1></pmx:SNDR_CHG_CCY1>
                   
                   <pmx:SNDR_CHG_AMT1></pmx:SNDR_CHG_AMT1>
                   
                   <pmx:SNDR_CHG_CCY2></pmx:SNDR_CHG_CCY2>
                   
                   <pmx:SNDR_CHG_AMT2></pmx:SNDR_CHG_AMT2>
                   
                   <pmx:SNDR_CHG_CCY3></pmx:SNDR_CHG_CCY3>
                   
                   <pmx:SNDR_CHG_AMT3></pmx:SNDR_CHG_AMT3>
                   
                   <pmx:SNDR_CHG_CCY4></pmx:SNDR_CHG_CCY4>
                   
                   <pmx:SNDR_CHG_AMT4></pmx:SNDR_CHG_AMT4>
                   
                   <pmx:SNDR_CHG_CCY5></pmx:SNDR_CHG_CCY5>
                   
                   <pmx:SNDR_CHG_AMT5></pmx:SNDR_CHG_AMT5>
                   
                   <pmx:SNDR_CHG_CCY6></pmx:SNDR_CHG_CCY6>
                   
                   <pmx:SNDR_CHG_AMT6></pmx:SNDR_CHG_AMT6>
                   
                   <pmx:RCVR_CHG_CCY></pmx:RCVR_CHG_CCY>
                   
                   <pmx:RCVR_CHG_AMT></pmx:RCVR_CHG_AMT>
                   
                   <pmx:TIME_IND_1></pmx:TIME_IND_1>
                   
                   <pmx:TIME_IND_2></pmx:TIME_IND_2>
                   
                   <pmx:TIME_IND_3></pmx:TIME_IND_3>
                   
                   <pmx:REGULATORY_DETAILS1></pmx:REGULATORY_DETAILS1>
                   
                   <pmx:REGULATORY_DETAILS2></pmx:REGULATORY_DETAILS2>
                   
                   <pmx:REGULATORY_DETAILS3></pmx:REGULATORY_DETAILS3>
                   
                   <pmx:TRANSACTION_TYPE></pmx:TRANSACTION_TYPE>
                   
                   <pmx:DEBIT_ENTRY_DATE>2021-03-31</pmx:DEBIT_ENTRY_DATE>
                   
                   <pmx:CREDIT_ENTRY_DATE>2021-03-31</pmx:CREDIT_ENTRY_DATE>
                   
                   <pmx:RCVR_CHG_COLLECTED></pmx:RCVR_CHG_COLLECTED>
                   
                   <pmx:HOST_CODE></pmx:HOST_CODE>
                   <pmx:TXN_REF_NO></pmx:TXN_REF_NO>
                   
                   <pmx:GPI_ENABLED></pmx:GPI_ENABLED>
                   
                   <pmx:GPI_UETR></pmx:GPI_UETR>
                   
                   <pmx:CHARGE_AC_BRN></pmx:CHARGE_AC_BRN>
                   
                   <pmx:CHARGE_AC_NO></pmx:CHARGE_AC_NO>
                   
                   <pmx:ENVELOPE_CONTENTS1></pmx:ENVELOPE_CONTENTS1>
                   
                   <pmx:ENVELOPE_CONTENTS2></pmx:ENVELOPE_CONTENTS2>
                   
                   <pmx:ENVELOPE_CONTENTS3></pmx:ENVELOPE_CONTENTS3>
                   
                   <pmx:ENVELOPE_CONTENTS4></pmx:ENVELOPE_CONTENTS4>
                   
                   <pmx:ENVELOPE_CONTENTS5></pmx:ENVELOPE_CONTENTS5>
                   
                   <pmx:GPI_IN_ENABLED></pmx:GPI_IN_ENABLED>
                   
                   <pmx:DR_AC_NO>000000100005004USD</pmx:DR_AC_NO>
                   
                   <pmx:ACTIVATION_DATE>2021-03-31</pmx:ACTIVATION_DATE>
                   
                   <pmx:BRANCH_OF_INPUT>000</pmx:BRANCH_OF_INPUT>
                   
                   <pmx:PREFUNDED_PAYMENTS></pmx:PREFUNDED_PAYMENTS>
                   
                   <pmx:FX_REF_NO></pmx:FX_REF_NO>
                   
                   <pmx:TEMPLATE_ID>BM001</pmx:TEMPLATE_ID>
                   
                   <pmx:SSI_LABEL></pmx:SSI_LABEL>
                   
                   <pmx:CUSTOMER_NO>000100005</pmx:CUSTOMER_NO>
                   
                   <pmx:SUPPRESS_DEBIT_CONFIRMATION></pmx:SUPPRESS_DEBIT_CONFIRMATION>
                   
                   <pmx:SUPPRESS_COVER_MESSAGE></pmx:SUPPRESS_COVER_MESSAGE>
                   
                   <pmx:SUPPRESS_PAYMENT_MESSAGE></pmx:SUPPRESS_PAYMENT_MESSAGE>
                   
                   <pmx:PROCESS_WITHOUT_COVER></pmx:PROCESS_WITHOUT_COVER>
                   
                   <pmx:SUPPRESS_RECEIVE_NOTICE></pmx:SUPPRESS_RECEIVE_NOTICE>
                   
                   <pmx:INSTRUCTED_CCY_IND></pmx:INSTRUCTED_CCY_IND>
                   
                   <pmx:AWI_BIC_DESC></pmx:AWI_BIC_DESC>
                   
                   <pmx:BENE_BIC_DESC></pmx:BENE_BIC_DESC>
                   
                   <pmx:BENE_INST_BIC_DESC></pmx:BENE_INST_BIC_DESC>
                   
                   <pmx:BRANCH_NAME></pmx:BRANCH_NAME>
                   
                   <pmx:CRED_NAME></pmx:CRED_NAME>
                   
                   <pmx:DEBTOR_NAME></pmx:DEBTOR_NAME>
                   
                   <pmx:HOST_CODE_DESCRIPTION></pmx:HOST_CODE_DESCRIPTION>
                   
                   <pmx:INTERMEDIARY_BIC_DESC></pmx:INTERMEDIARY_BIC_DESC>
                   
                   <pmx:NETWORK_CODE_DESC>SWIFT1</pmx:NETWORK_CODE_DESC>
                   
                   <pmx:ORD_CUST_BIC_CODE_DESC></pmx:ORD_CUST_BIC_CODE_DESC>
                   
                   <pmx:ORD_INST_BIC_CODE_DESC></pmx:ORD_INST_BIC_CODE_DESC>
                   
                   <pmx:OUR_CORRES_BIC_CODE_DESC></pmx:OUR_CORRES_BIC_CODE_DESC>
                   
                   <pmx:RCVR_CORRES_BIC_CODE_DESC></pmx:RCVR_CORRES_BIC_CODE_DESC>
                   
                   <pmx:SOURCECODE_DESC></pmx:SOURCECODE_DESC>
                   
                   <pmx:THIRD_REIMB_INST2_BIC_DESC></pmx:THIRD_REIMB_INST2_BIC_DESC>
                   
                   <pmx:CR_AC_CCY_NAME></pmx:CR_AC_CCY_NAME>
                   
                   <pmx:DR_AC_CCY_NAME></pmx:DR_AC_CCY_NAME>
                   
                   <pmx:RCVR_DESC></pmx:RCVR_DESC>
                   
                   <pmx:RCVR_OF_COVR_DESC></pmx:RCVR_OF_COVR_DESC>
                   
                   <pmx:TXN_ARCH_DT></pmx:TXN_ARCH_DT>
                   
                   <pmx:Payment-Chain>

                   </pmx:Payment-Chain>
                   
                   <pmx:Brn-Px-Out-Txn-Chg>
                      
                   </pmx:Brn-Px-Out-Txn-Chg>
                </pmx:Contract-Master-Full>
             </pmx:FCUBS_BODY>
          </pmx:CREATEXBORDEROUTSI_FSFS_REQ>
       </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
```

I have been facing an issue while calling webservice request using SOAP XML request message, through PLSQL,
I am getting the below issue,

```
<faultcode>ns0:Client</faultcode><faultstring>Cannot find dispatch method for {http://pmts.ofss.com/ws/PMXborderOutSIService}CREATEXBORDEROUTSI_FSFS_REQ</faultstring></ns0'.
```

Answer (score 0):

This typically means that the operation that should be invoked via this request could not be found.

This part of the error message looks suspicious:

```
{http://pmts.ofss.com/ws/PMXborderOutSIService}CREATEXBORDEROUTSI_FSFS_REQ
```

Normally, if everything works it should be with a '/' at the end, so should be:

```
{http://pmts.ofss.com/ws/PMXborderOutSIService/}CREATEXBORDEROUTSI_FSFS_REQ
```

Maybe adding / in request here:

```
<pmx:SERVICE>PMXborderOutSIService</pmx:SERVICE>
```

will help